# How to store the data from text fields which are in HTMLl to my Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; 
var left, opacity, scale; 
var animating; 

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 

 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 next_fs.show(); 

 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;

   left = (now * 50)+"%";

   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="reg.js"></script>
<script src="regi.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="registration.css">
</head>



<body>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
    <li>College Information</li>
    <li>Data Setup</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <input type="date" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">College Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 2</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="College name" />
    <input type="text" name="loc" placeholder="College Location" />
    <input type="text" name="purcourse" placeholder="Pursuing Course" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <form action="https://mahesh-5ff57.firebaseio.com" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </fieldset>
</form>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCROIg2ho_6RB50I_r2wce1Lmi0tjkvoCU",
    authDomain: "mahesh-5ff57.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mahesh-5ff57.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "mahesh-5ff57.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "474946290928"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="./registration.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

I need to store the data into Firebase database which is entered by the user into textfields in HTML. Help me writing the code in JavaScript.

Totally, there are 3 steps in my html page. After filling the textfields and clicking next in step1, it goes to step2, and again after filling the data in these fields it goes to step3, and when I click on submit button, it should store all the data from HTML to Firebase.

Comment: does firebase use SQL?

Comment: Firebase is a cloud-hosted NoSQL database. Data is stored as JSON, synced across connected devices in milliseconds, and available when your app goes offline.